Issues updating seaborn plots
I have an application that generates a seaborn plot and then I need to add some additional data to that plot at a later time. If I show the plot after the initial data is plotted I cannot get it to update. Below is a simplified example reproducing the issue.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


class DataPlotter:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.df = df

    def plot_samples(self, x: str, y: str):
        sns.lineplot(data=self.df, x=x, y=y, ax=self.ax)
        plt.ylim([1, 5])
        plt.xlim([0, 4])
        
        plt.show() #If this line is omitted the code works

        self.ax.axvline(x=2, color='green', linestyle='--', linewidth=2, label='x=5')
        
        plt.show()
        


dict_data = {'c1': [1, 2,3], 'c2': [2,3,4]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_data) 

plotter = DataPlotter(df)
plotter.plot_samples(x='c1', y='c2')


plt.show() closes (and clears) the plot when you close the plot window.  You could use plt.pause(...) to show the plot during some interval (in seconds) without clearing the plot.
Or, you could put the code that plots the first part of the plot into a separate function and call it again.
Here is how the code could look like with a boolean telling whether you want to plot both parts. The exact behavior depends on the environment and backed where the code is run.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

class DataPlotter:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.df = df

    def plot_samples(self, x: str, y: str, plot_only_first_part: bool = False):
        sns.lineplot(data=self.df, x=x, y=y, ax=self.ax)
        plt.ylim([1, 5])
        plt.xlim([0, 4])

        if not plot_only_first_part:
            self.ax.axvline(x=2, color='green', linestyle='--', linewidth=2, label='x=5')

        plt.show()


dict_data = {'c1': [1, 2, 3], 'c2': [2, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)

plotter = DataPlotter(df)
plotter.plot_samples(x='c1', y='c2', plot_only_first_part=True)
plotter.plot_samples(x='c1', y='c2')

